# bind symbolic link turning red post named restart

Tags: dns, unix, bind

Need some help with bind-chroot

We are running below version of bind and bind-chroot

bind-9.11.2-lp151.10.1.x86_64

bind-chrootenv-9.11.2-lp151.10.1.x86_64

Our Automation code is running to add Zone files to /var/lib/named/etc/named.conf only and not to /etc/named.conf

So in order to reflect the zone files created in /var/lib/named/etc/named.conf in /etc/named.conf, I created a symbolic link in /etc as "ln -s /var/lib/named/etc/named.conf named.conf" to reflect as below
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Dec  9 11:03 named.conf -> /var/lib/named/etc/named.conf

Now, when I make changes to file in /var/lib/named/etc/named.conf and do a "service named restart"
The file in /etc/named.conf fails to Load

Error messages in /var/log/messages as below

`2021-12-09T11:04:46.684677+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: Stopped Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS). 2021-12-09T11:04:46.685049+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: Starting Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)... 2021-12-09T11:04:46.735359+05:30 lavasadns1 named.init[2509]: Starting name server BIND cp: cannot stat '/etc/named.conf': No such file or directory 2021-12-09T11:04:46.844546+05:30 lavasadns1 named.init[2509]: open: /etc/named.conf: file not found 2021-12-09T11:04:46.847806+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: named.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=6 2021-12-09T11:04:46.848137+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS). 2021-12-09T11:04:46.848475+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: named.service: Unit entered failed state. 2021-12-09T11:04:46.848772+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 2021-12-09T11:05:31.657460+05:30 lavasadns1 systemd[1]: Starting Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)... 2021-12-09T11:05:31.666976+05:30 lavasadns1 named.init[2573]: Name server configuration file /etc/named.conf does not exist.`

and the Symbolic link changes color to Red.
Why is this happening?
And how can avoid this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting `bind`/`named` runs `/usr/sbin/named.init`.

In there, is a function called `checkAndCopyConfigFiles`.

In there is the line `rm -f ${CHROOT_PREFIX}/${configfile}`

You made a symlink from `/etc/named.conf` to `/var/lib/named/etc/named.conf`, now when that script runs, it deleted `/var/lib/named/etc/named.conf`.

So, the script deleted `/var/lib/named/etc/named.conf`, and attempted to copy the endpoint of the symlink, `/etc/named.conf`, which no longer exists, since it has already deleted it.

This results in a dangling symlink reference and hence turns `red`.

Your crafted `named.conf` no longer exists.

If you can get it back, you have 3 choices.

1. Have your code alter the `/etc/named.conf` and any other files within `/etc/` rather than within `/var/lib/named/etc`.
2. Edit `/usr/sbin/named.init` and craft your own which handles such a situation.
3. Remove `bind-chrootenv` and craft your own startup script.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer helped a lot